# Is there an equivalent of BitBlt in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi

Is there a way to invert a region of the screen using WPF?
In Win32, I would do BitBlt ( .... DSTINVERT ...).
Of course, I would use Interop but that seems pretty messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd look at using [Pixel Shaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901594(VS.95).aspx). They're GPU optimized so they will likely run more quickly. There's an [InvertImage effect available on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/wpffx).

Comment: No, it requires .NET 3.5 SP1. I think the "WPF way" to do it in .NET 3.0 is to use a CustomBitmapEffect (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771475.aspx), but there may be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint.FillReversibleRectangle.  It's not WPF, but it is .NET and "less messy".